# Disable WebSession creation when using spring-security with spring-webflux

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-webflux

I am running a stateless spring-boot application with a rest api and want to disable the creation of WebSessions as described https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session

I have created my own WebSessionManager that does not store the session.

```
   @Bean
   public WebSessionManager webSessionManager() {
       return new WebSessionManager() {
           @Override
           @NonNull
           public Mono<WebSession> getSession(@NonNull final ServerWebExchange exchange) {
               return Mono.just(new WebSession() {

                   @Override
                   @NonNull
                   public String getId() {
                       return "";
                   }

                   @Override
                   @NonNull
                   public Map<String, Object> getAttributes() {
                       return new HashMap<>();
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void start() {
                   }

                   @Override
                   public boolean isStarted() {
                       return true;
                   }

                   @Override
                   @NonNull
                   public Mono<Void> changeSessionId() {
                       return Mono.empty();
                   }

                   @Override
                   @NonNull
                   public Mono<Void> invalidate() {
                       return Mono.empty();
                   }

                   @Override
                   @NonNull
                   public Mono<Void> save() {
                       return Mono.empty();
                   }

                   @Override
                   public boolean isExpired() {
                       return false;
                   }

                   @Override
                   @NonNull
                   public Instant getCreationTime() {
                       return Instant.now();
                   }

                   @Override
                   @NonNull
                   public Instant getLastAccessTime() {
                       return Instant.now();
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void setMaxIdleTime(@NonNull final Duration maxIdleTime) {
                   }

                   @Override
                   @NonNull
                   public Duration getMaxIdleTime() {
                       return Duration.ofMinutes(1);
                   }
               });
           }
       };
   }
```

It works but I wonder if there is a better way to not create a session.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Issue #6552: Session Creation Policy with Webflux Security](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6552) is going to be fixed by Spring team.

> The problem is that the request cache is being invoked for every request to see if there is a value saved to replay and thus the WebSession is being looked up for every request. Since the WebSession is being looked up with an invalid session id, Spring WebFlux invalidates the SESSION cookie. ~ [rwinch](https://github.com/rwinch)

Solution suggested by [DarrenJiang1990](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6552#issuecomment-519398510) is:

```
.and().securityContextRepository(NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance())
```

> The security context in a WebFlux application is stored in a ServerSecurityContextRepository. Its WebSessionServerSecurityContextRepository implementation, which is used by default, stores the context in session. Configuring a NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository instead would make our application stateless

You can track the progress of patching in [Issue #7157 ServerRequestCacheWebFilter causes WebSession to be read every request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/7157).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 

SecurityWebFilterChain won't solve the issue with creating websessions though.

Comment: I have wrote comment on Github Issue about this SO question, hopefully they will patch `.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)` into WebFlux shortly.

Comment: The Spring team is on the track to fix this problem. I have update the answer with suggested workaround.

Comment: @Xarvalus I guess you might modify your answer. It seems like the `.and().securityContextRepository(NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance())` is the primary solution and the rest is maybe completely redundant :)

Answer (score 6):

I've disabled WebSessionManager by the following trick

```
  @Bean
  public WebSessionManager webSessionManager() {
    // Emulate SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS
    return exchange -> Mono.empty();
  }
```

All other solutions didn't help for me.

Answer (score 2):

Use the: NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository intended for this purpose.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@ComponentScan(value = {"my.package.security"})
public class SpringSecurityConfig2 {
    @Autowired private MyHeaderExchangeMatcher myHeaderExchangeMatcher;
    @Autowired private MyReactiveAuthenticationManager myReactiveAuthenticationManager;
    @Autowired private MyTokenAuthenticationConverter myTokenAuthenticationConverter;

    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain springWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http.httpBasic().disable().formLogin().disable().csrf().disable().logout().disable();

        http...
                .addFilterAt(webFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHORIZATION)
                ...;

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationWebFilter webFilter() {
        AuthenticationWebFilter authenticationWebFilter =
                new AuthenticationWebFilter(myReactiveAuthenticationManager);
        authenticationWebFilter.setServerAuthenticationConverter(myTokenAuthenticationConverter);
        authenticationWebFilter.setRequiresAuthenticationMatcher(myHeaderExchangeMatcher);

        // NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository is used to for stateless sessions so no session or state is persisted between requests.
        // The client must send the Authorization header with every request.
        NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository sessionConfig = NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance();

        authenticationWebFilter.setSecurityContextRepository(sessionConfig);
        return authenticationWebFilter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, (at least for Reactive services) this is insufficient.  I see session still being created even if I add this.  The only thing that really made this stateless is @Dmitry's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67005365/918858)