# Spring Webflux: Schedulers.boundedElastic grows infinetely

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm monitoring my Spring WebFlux app with VisualVM and I'm noticing a strange thing.

The `boundedElastic` threads are keeps increasing.

[image: bounded elastic threads]

The thing is that I don't use `boundedElastic` scheduler in my app app manually.

After debugging I found this

[image: boundedElastic method stacktract]

Seems that `InMemoryWebSessionStore` requests the `Schedulers.boundedElastic`. The thing is that this method does not require any authorization though I have Spring Security in the dependencies.

How can I disable this behavior? I don't want my app to grow some thread pool size infinitely. Especially when those threads aren't even used.

P.S. Maybe this issue comes from the fact that I inject `ServerWebExchange` as the controller method parameter. But I need it to retrieve the request's cookies and headers

Comment: The thread pool is not infinite. As its name says it is bounded. Its size depends on the number of CPU cores. IIRC it is 10 times of number of CPU cores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it. `WebSessionManager` is auto-configured. I have to declare my own no-op implementation. Here is the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56056404/disable-websession-creation-when-using-spring-security-with-spring-webflux).