# Spring WebFlux thread model

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I can't understand the WebFlux threading model.

As far as I know when request comes to server it is caught by event loop, which immediately registers callback. After that request is passed further to platform where it can be processed by any available thread. After processing platform sends completion notification to event loop which on receiving it triggers callback and returns the result to caller.

Am I right?

I have simple controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/category")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class CategoryController implements CategoryApi {

    private final CategoryService categoryService;

    @Override
    @GetMapping(path = "/all")
    public ResponseEntity<Flux<CategoryInfo>> getAllCategories() {
        log.info("Request for categories");
        return ResponseEntity.ok(categoryService.getAllCategories());
    }
}
```

And simple service:

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class DefaultCategoryService implements CategoryService {

    private final CategoryRepository categoryRepository;
    private final CategoryMapper categoryMapper;

    @Override
    public Flux<CategoryInfo> getAllCategories() {
        return categoryRepository.findAll()
                .map(it -> debug(it, "findAll"))
                .filter(filterUncategorized())
                .map(categoryMapper::toView)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel());
    }
}
```

`debug` method just logs passed element along with string, nothing interesting.

When I send request via JMeter I see this in my logs:

```
2022-11-24 18:19:29.450  INFO 55376 --- [     parallel-2] c.e.stts.controller.CategoryController   : Request for categories
2022-11-24 18:19:29.491  INFO 55376 --- [actor-tcp-nio-1] com.epam.stts.utils.LoggingUtils         : Category@15e5cb5d =>> [findAll]
2022-11-24 18:19:29.491  INFO 55376 --- [actor-tcp-nio-1] com.epam.stts.utils.LoggingUtils         : Category@5a208124 =>> [findAll]
2022-11-24 18:19:29.491  INFO 55376 --- [actor-tcp-nio-1] com.epam.stts.utils.LoggingUtils         : Category@aa5de115 =>> [findAll]
```

And this is what confuses me.
If I change `Schedulers.parallel()` to `Schedulers.boundedElastic()` or `Schedulers.single()` or whatever then nothing changes, I still see only `reactor-tcp-nio-1` thread doing its job!

But when I use `Schedulers.boundedElastic()` then in [JProfiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTdSI.png) i see many boundedElastic threads in **WAIT** state.

If I use `publishOn` after calling the repository then as expected all downstream operators (i.e. filter and map in this case) are processed on specified scheduler worker.

So please help me understand how it is supposed to be working.

What is `reactor-tcp-nio-1` thread and why it is the only thread that does all processing?
Why `subscribeOn` does not pass the execution to another worker?
Why reactor creates many boundedElastic threads but they are all waiting and do nothing?

I use **Java 17** and **Spring Boot 2.7.5.**

Much appreciated!

Comment: This answer your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72857726/spring-webflux-schedulers-boundedelastic-grows-infinetely

Comment: Not quite. I configured my security just as in answer for this post, and besides I don't see any InMemorySessionStorage. And in my case boundedElastic threads are created only when I explicitly use corresponding Scheduler. I'm more interested in why my subscribeOn operator has no effect on the flow and why do these boundedElastic threads are not in use while created.

Comment: you can start by reading https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#schedulers so you understand what a scheduler is, it SCHEDULES jobs, it does not do the actual work. The event loop does the work. And if the system feels it only needs one thread to schedule jobs on the event loop there is no need to have multiple threads scheduling work.