# Spring Boot - No SecurityContext found in WebSession

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, authorization

Currently I have a spring cloud gateway service and a number of other services. The gateway intercepts each request, checks if authorization is present and according allows/denies accessing a certain resource.

I keep getting 401 Unauthorized so upon enabling debug messages, I found the following

```
17-09-2023 13:41:43.189 [parallel-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.s.DefaultWebSessionManager .org.springframework.web.server.session.DefaultWebSessionManager lambda$createWebSession$3 - Created new WebSession.
17-09-2023 13:41:43.190 [parallel-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.c.WebSessionServerSecurityContextRepository .org.springframework.security.web.server.context.WebSessionServerSecurityContextRepository lambda$load$1 - No SecurityContext found in WebSession: 'org.springframework.web.server.session.InMemoryWebSessionStore$InMemoryWebSession@1c19c273'
17-09-2023 13:41:43.196 [parallel-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.u.m.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher .org.springframework.security.web.server.util.matcher.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher lambda$matches$0 - Trying to match using PathMatcherServerWebExchangeMatcher{pattern='/logout', method=POST}
17-09-2023 13:41:43.197 [parallel-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.u.m.PathPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher .org.springframework.security.web.server.util.matcher.PathPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher lambda$matches$1 - Request 'POST /auth/authenticate-contractor' doesn't match 'POST /logout'
17-09-2023 13:41:43.198 [parallel-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.u.m.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher .org.springframework.security.web.server.util.matcher.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher lambda$matches$2 - No matches found
17-09-2023 13:41:43.202 [parallel-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.a.DelegatingReactiveAuthorizationManager .org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.DelegatingReactiveAuthorizationManager lambda$check$1 - Checking authorization on '/auth' using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedReactiveAuthorizationManager@2b6b1534
17-09-2023 13:41:43.205 [parallel-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.c.WebSessionServerSecurityContextRepository .org.springframework.security.web.server.context.WebSessionServerSecurityContextRepository lambda$load$1 - No SecurityContext found in WebSession: 'org.springframework.web.server.session.InMemoryWebSessionStore$InMemoryWebSession@1c19c273'
17-09-2023 13:41:43.207 [parallel-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.a.AuthorizationWebFilter .org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.AuthorizationWebFilter lambda$filter$3 - Authorization failed: Access Denied
17-09-2023 13:41:43.213 [parallel-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.c.WebSessionServerSecurityContextRepository .org.springframework.security.web.server.context.WebSessionServerSecurityContextRepository lambda$load$1 - No SecurityContext found in WebSession: 'org.springframework.web.server.session.InMemoryWebSessionStore$InMemoryWebSession@1c19c273'
17-09-2023 13:41:43.230 [parallel-2] DEBUG o.s.c.s.i.web.TraceWebFilter .org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceWebFilter$MonoWebFilterTrace$WebFilterTraceSubscriber terminateSpan - Handled send of RealSpan(3c5c588d8857df88/3c5c588d8857df88)
17-09-2023 13:41:43.235 [parallel-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.a.HttpWebHandlerAdapter .org.springframework.core.log.LogFormatUtils traceDebug - [787638e7-1] Completed 401 UNAUTHORIZED
```

I tried to set the authentication object either using `SecurityContextHolder` or `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder` but none seem to work so far.

Below is the setup:
Spring Boot: `v2.7.14`
pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Here's the custom `WebFilter` I have implemented

```
@Component
class AuthFilter(
    private val firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth
): WebFilter {

    override fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: WebFilterChain): Mono<Void> {
        
            val authentication = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                "ROLE_USER",
                null,
                listOf(SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"))
            )

            return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .map { it.authentication = authentication }
                .then(chain.filter(exchange))
    }
}
```

And here's the security config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
class SecurityConfig(
    private val firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth
) {

    @Bean
    fun securityWebFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain {

        return http
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .authorizeExchange()
            .anyExchange().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilterAt(AuthFilter(firebaseAuth), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
            .build()
    }
}
```

What else could be missing to fix the unauthorized error?

Comment: are you using spring session, because your logs seem to suggest that but you have written none about it in your question.

Comment: @Toerktumlare There is nothing related to sessions in the whole service. Maybe there is some kind of misconfiguration, that's why I shared the current setup.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem related to: [Disable WebSession creation when using spring-security with spring-webflux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56056404/disable-websession-creation-when-using-spring-security-with-spring-webflux)

you should to add

`.and().securityContextRepository(NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance())`

in you Security Configuration filter

all description of the issue in the provided link.

Comment: Would be great if you can show the suggestion in code block like question author has done, preferably modifying the author's code with your suggestion in code block format